# Fair and biased dice problem

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

We have 2 dice - one is a fair die while the faces of the other die are 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5. We pick one of the two dice at random and throwing it gives a 2. What is the probability that we picked up the fair die?

Comment: As a way to develop intuition, say you threw the fair die $6^n$ times for large $n$.  How many $2's$ would you get?  What about the biased one?

Comment: You can do this via Bayes' theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For short, lets write BD= Biased dice, FD=Fair dice & Two= Threw a $2$ then
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(BD \text{ and } Two)=P(BD)\times P( Two \text{ on the Biased dice})=\frac{?}{?} \\
P(FD \text{ and } Two)=\underbrace{P(FD)}_{\frac{1}{2}}\times P( Two \text{ on the Fair dice})=\frac{?}{?} \\
P( Two)=\underbrace{P(BD \text{ and } Two)+P(FD \text{ and } Two)}_{\text{These events are mutually exclusive}} =\frac{?}{?} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the conditional probability formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(FD \mid Two)= \frac{P(FD \text{ and } Two)}{P(Two)} = \frac{?}{?}.
\end{eqnarray*}

> $P(FD \mid Two)= \frac{\frac{1}{12}}{\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Can you explain how to calculate the P(FD and Two)?

Comment: So P(BD) = P(FD) = $1/2$ right?

Comment: That's right ...